# Address of operator can initlize a pointer but the fill-in value is garbage

Tags: c++, c, pointers, address-operator

Pointers to uninitialized memory will causing error. Deference such pointer represents a invalid address.

```
int *pi;                                                                                                                                                          
printf("%i\n",*pi);
```

The above code leads to the using uninitialized variable Error.

```
error: ‘pi’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

However, when printing the address first, seems the pointer is initialized by a valid address but filled in with invalid data

```
int *pi; 
printf("%p\n",&pi); //address printing                                                                                                                                                       
printf("%i\n",*pi);
```

which prints out:

```
0x7ffeea9313c8 //valid virtual address
-125990072 //invalid data
```

**Question**:

Does the address of operator (&) initialize a pointer? If not, please correct the wrong understandings.

Comment: Any attempt to dereference an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior

Comment: @AndyG so this is decided by the compiler

Comment: A compiler isn't required to emit an error in the first case - in fact, it is allowed to compile "fine": https://godbolt.org/g/XBuK4P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you pass the address of this pointer to a function, compiler can no longer tell whether it has been initialized inside that function.

Consider the following function:

```
void init_ptr(int **ptr) { *ptr = some_valid_addr; }
```

Then you call:

```
int *pi; 
init_ptr(&pi);
```

You know `printf()` won't init the pointer, but compiler doesn't have enough information to tell the difference.